# Spring REST API Swagger UI @ModelAttribute request URL and parameter type

Tags: spring, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

i have some problems trying to make my swagger UI return what i want.
The problem is that i want to display the areaName as a *path* parameter type NOT a *query* in the Swagger UI. I can do that by using `@PathVariable` String "areaName".

BUT i want to validate the areaname in a seperate requestclass and now im trying to use `@Valid` `@ModelAttribute` instead. The problem with this is that Swagger gives me a boring request URL like:

/v1/areas/***{areaName}***/series?***areaName=testarea***&from=20151201

I want it to show the same way as when im using `@PathVariable`:

/v1/areas/***testarea***/series?from=20151201

I have tried playing around with the `@ApiParam` in the requestclass and even tried to hidden=true to keep a `@PathVariable` in the controller and just hide the `@ApiParam` in the requestclass to not get a duplicate of areaName in the Swagger UI but the hidden doesn't seem to work. Im using Swagger/SwaggerUI version 2.3.0.. Any ideas?

Requestclass:

```
public class AreaSeriesRequest {

@ApiParam(value = "Area selector, wich area to get series from.", required = true)
@EnergyAreas
private String areaName;

public String getAreaName() {
    return AreaName;
}

public void setAreaName(String areaName) {
    this.areaName = areaName;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{areaName}/series", method = GET, produces = json)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public Page<GroupSeriesDto> getAreaSeriesPaginated(
            //@PathVariable String areaName,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute AreaSeriesRequest seriesRequest, BindingResult seriesResult,
            @ModelAttribute PagingRequest pagingRequest,
            Principal currentUser) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way i worked around this was to still use the @PathVariable but instead of @Valid @ModelAttribute on the areaName i did a seperate validator for this parameter.

```
public class AreaValidator implements Validator {

private static final List<String> types = Arrays.asList(
        "ALL",
        "XX1",
        "XX2",
        "XX3",
        "XX4"
);

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
    return String.class.equals(clazz);
}

@Override
public void validate(Object target, Errors e) {
    String value = (String) target;

    if (value == null || !types.contains(value.toUpperCase())) {
        e.reject(String.format("Area '%s' does not exist", value));
    }
}
```

And then used it in the controller like:

```
new AreaValidator().validate(areaName, seriesResult);

if (seriesResult.hasErrors())
throw new AreaNotFoundException(areaName);
```